# rails delete user session path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the devise gem to make authentication work in my app.

Here's the code I have for signing out:

```
    <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

I have tried this as well:

```
    <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path%>
```

Both of which when I click on sign out I get :

```
No route matches [GET] "/users/destroy"
```

However when I run rake routes, you can see it (just not GET):

```
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Can u pass routes for devise and you have customize routes? You can use  devise_scope :user do
    get '/login' => 'devise/sessions#new'
    get '/logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  end and in UI <%= link_to "Logout",  logout_path%>

Comment: have you included the necessary js file for making `:method => :delete` on links work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could this help you in the right direction?

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1195

Answer (score 6):

Mitch's answer was close but did not work for me, instead the following syntax did:

`<%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>`

Answer (score 2):

Roger's link above is v useful.

I used the following syntax, which worked:

```
<%= link_to "Log out", destroy_session_path(:user), :method => :delete %>
```

Answer (score 0):

if using turbo, and you've tried everything else, make sure you ran the

```
Run ./bin/rails turbo:install
```

in command line. fixed it for me using turbo.